# Implement google plus interactive post sharing using php (if possible)

Tags: php, yii

Guys i want to implement google+ interactive post sharing using php but not getting proper documentation or link. In [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive#javascript_api) only java script method is provided. Please provide any link or suggest any good way to perform this if it is possible. thanks in advance...